# In Sleeping Dogs, which DLC do I need to do all achievements?

Tags: achievements, sleeping-dogs

The Game has quite some DLC's on it's list in the Steam Store.

Which ones do I need to buy to be able to get all the achievements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sleeping Dogs have only two expansion packs (so far) that give you achievements:

- Year of the Snake
- Nightmare in North Point

trueachievements.com is usually a good website for all your achievement needs. Here is the link to the game page on the site. Scroll down for names of achievement-enabled DLCs.

http://www.trueachievements.com/Sleeping-Dogs/achievements.htm

Comment: Should be a popular answer today as Sleeping Dogs and all DLC is 75% off, but to buy it all would cost upwards of $30 (base game and these two DLC are just <10$ though)

Comment: Thanks Alain. I would probably have not included actual pricing since it's currency-dependent.